# How do you determine the Android wifi startScan method is complete in order to calculate the time taken for the wifi scan?

Tags: android, wifimanager

code for calculating start and end time of scan. Calling scanTime as soon as the scan starts and retTime as soon as the results are received, however, getting two retTimes and the difference between scanTime and retTime is not consistent

```
public void startService() { 
    br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            if (location != null) {
                retTime =  System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
                Log.i("end", Long.toString(retTime));
                sendResults(wifi.getScanResults(), androidID, Long.toString(retTime), location);
                Long result = retTime - scanTime;
            } else {
                Log.i("Location", "is Missing");
            }
        }

    };
    context.registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                setSleepTime(dataTimeDifference);
                while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                    wifi.startScan();
                    scanTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
                    Log.i("start", Long.toString(scanTime));
                    Thread.sleep(sleepingTime);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you know the scan is complete when the BroadcastReceiver is triggered.

This may not directly answer your question, but it seems that this might be a better way of implementing the functionality that you want.
Instead of using Thread.sleep() and a while loop in your Runnable, just rely on the BroadcastReceiver in order to determine when to start a new scan.

Also keep in mind that both the user and the OS can initiate scans, and your BroadcastReceiver will be triggered when those scans complete as well.

```
private final Runnable mStartScan = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           wifi.startScan();
        }
}; 

public void startService() { 
    br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

          String action = intent.getAction();
          if (action.equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)){

            if (location != null) {

                 sendResults(wifi.getScanResults(), androidID, Long.toString(retTime), location);

            } else {
                Log.i("Location", "is Missing");
            }

            t = new Thread(mStartScan);
            t.start(); 
          }  
        }

    };

    context.registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

    t = new Thread(mStartScan);
    t.start();
}
```